# Universal Link couldn't open the Target application in iOS

Tags: ssl, ios-universal-links, apple-app-site-associate

I trying to implement Universal Link for **A** app

But **A** domains (which have AASA file that contains **A** appID and path) couldn't open the **A** app

So I use **B** domain to open **A** app (I edited AASA file on **B** domain with same appID and path in **A** domain's AASA file)

finally **B** domain could open the **A** app

Both **A** and **B** domain pass the validation test by Branch AASA Validator

but difference was AASA file's response Header

`B.com/apple-app-site-association`'s Response Headers contains `Content-Security-Policy` and `Strict-Transport-Security` fields

but `A.com/apple-app-site-association`'s Response Headers not contain them

is this a reason that **A** domain cannot open **A** app?

Comment: is domain A SSL valid? https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/

Comment: @Horst Yes It pass that validation